# "Многие" — это большинство или меньшинство?

Tags: семантика, синонимы, значение

Является ли слово "многие" по своему смыслу синонимом слова "большинство"?
По толковому словарю Ефремовой, значение слова "многие" описывается как "составляющие неопределённо большое число, значительную часть кого-либо, чего-либо".
Если из 500 человек взять выборку в 200 человек, про этих 200 человек можно сказать "многие", но на самом деле они не являются значительной частью от 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Многие* — не синоним этих слов, но отнести его следует к меньшинству.

***Многие люди* — это *много людей*.** Если бы было большинство (больше половины), то так бы и сказали.

Слово "много" относительно. И даже более: оно субъективно.

Не сказал бы, что 200 из 500 — это не значительно (не имеет значения). Если вы потратили 200 долларов из 500, разве это не существенно?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139573/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd------).

Answer (score 1):

Верно рассуждаете. Например, возьмём предложение сказанное в неком городе в 90-хх: ‟Большинство ветеранов в нашем городе уже умерли”. Допустим, там жило 1000 ветеранов. Если умерло 800, то люди скажут ‟большинство”, потому что ‟большинство” говорят тогда, когда больше половины. Если умерло 200-400 (представим, что это сказали в 70-хх о ветеранах). то люди скажут ‟многие”. То есть словом ‟большинство” обозначают больше половины, а словом ‟многие” обозначают 20-40 процентов, если речь идёт о больших числах. Это всё, конечно, грубо говоря.

**О связи слов ‟много” и ‟многие”.**
‟Много” это наречие меры. Много чего-то или мало зависит от количественного стандарта для ситуации – 500 долларов много для карманных расходов для ребёнка, но мало для свадебного подарка.
‟Многие” – определительное местоимение. Ещё эти слова называют ‟квантификаторы”. Эти слова используют, когда хотят сделать утверждения о некой части совокупности. Примеры таких слов или сочетаний: большинство, некоторые, половина, малая часть, все, многие. То есть слово ‟многие” ограничивает совокупность. Как ограничивает? – Я грубо описал, как это происходит в общем. Как-то детально анализировать разные ситуации и детально описывать использование этого слова я не буду.